# Angular component level service inject another component level service

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

I have component which uses two different service at component level. Each service is responsible for their own specific logic for the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  providers: [ServiceA, ServiceB]
})
```

And at the same time i need some methods from `ServiceB` in `ServiceA`. So i made:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
  constructor(private serviceB: ServiceB){}

  someMethod() {
     this.serviceB.makeSomething(); 
  }
}
```

So the question is it ok to use services at component level in such way? How does it work? How does `ServiceA` use the same instance of `ServiceB` as in `MyComponent`?

**UPD**: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbfcxs?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) is simplified example what i have. I know that my example is not perfect, but i hope you will get it

Comment: You could define a `setServiceB(serviceB: ServiceB)` method in `ServiceA` and call it from the component constructor. Otherwise, `ServiceA` will not know which `ServiceB` instance to inject in its constructor (it would depend how it is provided).

Comment: What happends if you provide the services from an Angular module, instead of from the component?

Comment: @JonasPraem as i said, that services is reponsible for specific job for that component instance, for example `FocuseService` and `BlurService`. They can be only at the component level. Because when i have multiple `my-component` at the page - the services should work independent

Comment: Services are not instance dependant

Comment: @JonasPraem - According to [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-services-in-modules-vs-components): "each new instance of the UserEditorComponent gets its own cached service instance".

Answer (score 0):

For services, the official guide has:

- **Do create services with a single responsibility that is encapsulated by its context.**
- **Do create a new service once the service begins to exceed that singular purpose.**

This may be a good suggestion.

The original document is here [Single responsibility](https://angular.cn/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility-1).